# label size in panda plot (scatter_matrix)

Tags: python, pandas

How can I set the label size in a pandas plot?

In normal plot I do `plt.xlabel('a', size=20)`

```
In [76]: from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix

In [77]: df = DataFrame(randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

In [78]: scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')
Out[78]: 
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x9f39e44c>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x9f39842c>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x9f383fcc>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa58039cc>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa57f19ec>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa578e66c>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa5adb28c>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa5a9deec>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa5d67fec>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa5dc764c>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x9fdb354c>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x9e63756c>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa5d9ccac>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x9f6d1ecc>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa5d6f02c>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xa5848e0c>]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The return of `scatter_matrix()` is a number of axis, therefore, there is no easy way to set the font size in one pass (except override it using `plt.rcParam`, such as `plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 20` for changing the label size), and it has to be set one by one, such as: `plt.setp(axes[0,0].yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), 'size', 15)`

[image]

To have all the tick labels changed, assuming `Axes=scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randn
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix

df = pd.DataFrame(randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

Axes = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')

#y ticklabels
[plt.setp(item.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), 'size', 15) for item in Axes.ravel()]
#x ticklabels
[plt.setp(item.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), 'size', 5) for item in Axes.ravel()]
#y labels
[plt.setp(item.yaxis.get_label(), 'size', 20) for item in Axes.ravel()]
#x labels
[plt.setp(item.xaxis.get_label(), 'size', 3) for item in Axes.ravel()]
```

[image]

Comment: can you include the full code? I have only a limited knowledge of matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

`pandas.tools.plotting` is deprecated in new releases.

If you try:

`from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix`

You get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-d908f18459b1> in <module>
----> 1 from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tools'
```

This is a modified/updated version of @ct-zhu answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from   numpy.random import randn

df = pd.DataFrame(randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

Axes = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')

#y ticklabels
[plt.setp(item.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), 'size', 15) for item in Axes.ravel()]
#x ticklabels
[plt.setp(item.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), 'size', 5) for item in Axes.ravel()]
#y labels
[plt.setp(item.yaxis.get_label(), 'size', 20) for item in Axes.ravel()]
#x labels
[plt.setp(item.xaxis.get_label(), 'size', 3) for item in Axes.ravel()];
```

[image: Image: Scatter Matrix with Label Font Sizes modified]